# Calling a JS function on a nested iframe with Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I've made a site which handles online credit card payments. As part of the payment process an iframe is required on my site which works with an external security service to validate credit card data. I need to pass specific information to this iframe which it will use in a form post. I do this from my site by calling a function on this iframe, as follows:

```
var frame = window.frames["SecureFrame"];
frame.SetInnerFormValues(...);
```

This works fine in my dev environment. However, my site also needs to be run as an iframe on any client sites. So in the end, the client site will have an iframe pointing to my payment interface, which has a iframe pointing to the secure service. Both of these iframes are of course using SSL.

This seems to create an issue with the multiple nested frames on the client side. (Well, Chrome works fine, but Firefox doesn't)

When an end user is on a client site, an error occurs when my JS code above is executed. Firefox throws an error saying "TypeError: frame.SetInnerFormValues is not a function". I tried executing some code in the JS console to attempt to get to this SetInnerFormValues function on the secure frame, but all I'm getting is "Error: Permission denied to access property '...'" when just trying to access anything on my own site first.

Please, Ninja's of SO, I need your help!

Comment: Sounds like a classic cross-domain security hindrance (that's completely warranted). Browsers today rarely if ever let you access anything with JavaScript inside or from within an iFrame whose source is coming from a different domain. It's for your protection.

Comment: Firefox and Safari restrict permissions on iframes for security reasons (and they are right to do so). It is better to avoid using them and find another approach.

Comment: Ok, so I can't access anything on my nested site as an end user. Does the context in which my scripts execute, change, because it is now nested as an iframe in a client site? Wouldn't my site's scripts still be executed in its own context and thus be able to call the SetInnerFormValues function of its own child iframe? Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

Since the iFrame is loaded from another website, you can't do regular javascript function calls on it. That would be [cross-site scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_site_scripting). You need to set up an interface on your server that responds to SSL-secured (https:) POST requests to keep your users' information safe.